# Why does this bash script not work as an automator service?

Tags: terminal, finder, automator, bash, script

*I know very little about bash scripting or Terminal commands, this is all very new to me so please bear with me.*

---

### Original script

I would like to use a script I found on [littlefield.info](http://www.littlefield.info/software/learnt-bash-how-to-calculate-how-many-total-minutes-in-video-files.html) as an automator service. This is the original script:

```
for file in *.flv *.mov *.mp4
  do mediainfo "--Inform=Video;%Duration%" $file
done | awk '{total+=$0}END{total=total/1000}END{print strftime("%H:%M:%S",total,1)}'
```

Explained by the creator:

> 1. Cycle through every video file in a folder,
> 2. Passing it to the mediainfo program to extract the duration in milliseconds,
> 3. Passing that result to the awk program to add up all the numbers to give us a total,
> 4. Passing that to awk again to divide that number by 1000 to give the number of seconds,
> 5. Passing that that to the strftime function to display the result in Hours:Minutes:Seconds format.

### Modified script

I installed the [mediainfo](http://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo/Download/Mac_OS) CLI and started experimenting. Apparently `strftime` is not available on mac, so I had to look up another way on how to convert the seconds to readable output. I cobbled together the following script (probably horribly inefficient, but hey.. it works):

```
# the cd is needed for automator
cd "$1"

i=$(for file in *.flv *.mov *.mp4
        do mediainfo "--Inform=Video;%Duration%" $file
    done | awk '{total+=$0}END{print total}')

((i/=1000, sec=i%60, i/=60, min=i%60, hrs=i/60))
timestamp=$(printf "%dh%02dm%02ds" $hrs $min $sec)
echo -e "Total duration of video files in this folder:\n\n$timestamp" > _total_duration.txt
```

It works perfectly fine in Terminal. But running it as a service from Finder gives the following output:

> Total duration of video files in this folder:
>
> 0h00m00s

### awk variable problem

The duration shouldn't be 0. I started troubleshooting, and reduced the script to the following:

```
for file in *.flv *.mov *.mp4
    do mediainfo "--Inform=Video;%Duration%" $file
done | awk '{total+=$0}END{print total}'  > "test_file_awk.txt"
```

There seems to be a problem with the variable `total` in AWK. It doesn't output anything when run from Finder but works correctly from Terminal.

Do you guys have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start with a small example.

Fire up Automator and create a service with a single "Run Shell Script" step.

Set it to take Folders as input from Finder

Pass input as arguments. Shell is /bin/bash

Bash code:

```
cd "$@"

for file in *.mov *.flk *.mp4
    do
    ls -1 "$file" >> ~/Desktop/test_file_awk.txt
done
```

What this does it takes the directory you pass in as "$@" and goes into it then runs the command on all the files in that directory.

"$@" is in quotes to protect against spaces, as is "$file"

So, you can replicate this to your setup:

```
cd "$@"
i=$(for file in {*.flv,*.mov,*.mp4,*.m4v}
    do 
    /usr/local/bin/mediainfo "--Inform=Video;%Duration%" "$file"
done | awk '{total+=$0}END{print total}')

((i/=1000, sec=i%60, i/=60, min=i%60, hrs=i/60))
timestamp=$(printf "%dh%02dm%02ds" $hrs $min $sec)
echo -e "Total duration of video files in this folder:\n\n$timestamp" > _total_duration.txt
```

Personally, I would change the output to something like:

```
> ~/Desktop/"$@"_total_duration.txt
```

So that the data ends up on  your desktop in a file named for the folder, but I have a lot of media directories and I don't want txt files in them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But I still get 0h00m00s as output though. The variable `i` seems to be _empty_.

If I run this after the awk part: `echo "This is i: $(i)" > _total_duration.txt` I get this as output: "This is i: "

Comment: Try now, works for me.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a bunch. Why do you have to write `/usr/local/bin/` before the `mediainfo` command in Automator and not in Terminal?

Comment: Actually, not sure that's entirely required, but some automation environments (notably cron, autosys) don't run with a full user environment, and will require either that environment loaded, or full paths. I put it in to be sure as I was debugging.

Comment: Well, adding the full path did the trick. So thanks a lot :)

Comment: I'm on MacOS 10.15 & quotation `cd "$@"` doesn't work!. But `cd $@` works.